# Clarification on probability problem involving groups and combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Here's a question that I've thought of myself.

On an online Zoom meeting, the host divides $15$ participants into five groups of three people each. The next day, the host does the same. (The participants' names, for simplicity, are $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, \text{ and } O$.) What's the probability that if $ABC$ were in the same group the first time, they are in the same group the second time?

Here's my approach:

There are $\binom{15}{3} \cdot \binom{12}{3} \cdot \binom{9}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{3}{3}$ total groups. If we define one group to have the same members as yesterday, we have $12$ members left to form four different groups. We have $\binom{12}{3} \cdot \binom{9}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{3}{3}$ ways for the numerator. However, we need to use PIE since we overcount, so we calculate the total number of ways two groups have the same people.

This is just $\binom{9}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{3}{3}$ if we define two teams to be the same. And so on, for PIE.

I'm just not sure whether to multiply by $\binom{5}{2}$ in that last expression. Normally in PIE you would do so, but since I am defining a specific group to be chosen again, do I multiply? Maybe it would be $4$, since we already have one defined team but the second team can be any of the four others?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that the probability is:
$$
\frac{5 \cdot 3!12!}{15!} = \frac{1}{91}
$$

Comment: Oh, so you do multiply by $5$ @Adriano? Why? Since we're talking about one specific group being chosen again, then do we still multiply by $5$?

Comment: By "same group", do you mean one $particular$ group, or just together in a group ? In technical parlance, are the groups $labelled$ or $unlabelled$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is only asking about ABC, they aren't bothered about the rest.
Imagine 15 slots divided into 5 groups,
$\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}$  $\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}$ $\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}$  $\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}$  $\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}$

$If$ $the$ $groups$ $are$ $labelled$

A has 3 places available out of 15, B has 2 remaining places out of 14, etc.

so Pr = $\frac 3{15} \cdot\frac 2{14} \cdot\frac 1{13}$

$If$ $the$ $groups$ $are$ $unlabelled$

A can be anywhere, so Pr = $1 \cdot\frac2{14} \cdot\frac 1{13}$